# Customise setup.exe icon from default using InstallShield LE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, icons, installshield, installshield-le

So I am trying to figure out whether I can add a custom icon to the final install file (setup.exe). Currently, the project is using the InstallShield icon as shown below:

[image: InstallShield icon example for setup.exe]

I cannot find any field to change to customise the `setup.exe` icon.

Do I need to upgrade to InstallShield 2012 Express/Professional/Premier to be able to change this field? I don't want to use something like `Resource Hacker` to edit the contents of the `.exe` as this will change the hash of the file/may pose signing problems as well.

Currently using:

- InstallShield 2012 Spring Limited Edition
- Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @markmuetz, not as of yet, but I will do more research this week and get back to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is not supported by Install Shield Limited Edition. From the [Flexera website product features](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/promolanding/10909.htm):

> Specify Custom Icon and Version Resource Properties Modify the icon
>   and version resource properties to match your company and product
>   branding.

This only has ticks for the Premier and Professional versions of Install Shield, and I think this is talking about the installer's icon.

This leaves a tool such as Resource Hacker, but as eggy pointed out, this could cause problems.